# Authenticate Requests after login with GoogleSignInComponent in Angular Webapplication

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, google-signin, google-authentication

I am writing an Angular-Webapplication in which I want to list the Google Cloud Platform Projects of a signed in user.

To sign in the user I used the 'angular-google-signin' npm package from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-google-signin) with the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only' like mentioned in the [API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) from Google.

This returns an event that contains a gapi.auth2.GoogleUser with an AuthResponse that looks like the following:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "some token",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me openid email profile",
  "login_hint": "some hint",
  "expires_in": 2077,
  "id_token": "some id Token",
  "session_state": {
    "extraQueryParams": {
      "authuser": "0"
    }
  },
  "first_issued_at": 1536444745852,
  "expires_at": 1536448345852,
  "idpId": "google"
}
```

But I can't manage to create a request against the google API. The gapi.client is always undefined and also a simple REST-Request with the access_token in the header as Bearer: access_token doesn't work. What am I missing?

The callback of the angular-google-signin component looks like that and the user is successfully logged in:

```
  onGoogleSignInSuccess(event: GoogleSignInSuccess) {
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
    const googleUser: gapi.auth2.GoogleUser = event.googleUser;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(googleUser.getAuthResponse()));
    const id: string = googleUser.getId();
    const profile: gapi.auth2.BasicProfile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' +
      profile
        .getId());
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());

    // request({
    //   uri: 'https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects',
    //   method: 'GET',
    //   headers: {
    //     'Bearer': googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token
    //   }
    // }, res => {
    //   console.log(res);
    // });

    // gapi.client.load('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1').then((value: any) => {
    //   console.log(value);
    // }).catch((error: any) => {
    //   console.error(error);
    // });
  }
```

How do I create and authenticate a request to fetch the users projects? I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Alright I feel kinda dumb now:

adding the ?access_token=xxxxx to the url solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you simply incorrectly specified the header:

```
    request({
      uri: 'https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token
      }
    }, res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```